# Android Studio: todo aparece descuadrado

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

tengo un pequeño código en Android Studio con un par de botones, un EditText y un TextView, todo bastante básico. En la previsualización todo me sale más o menos como quiero, bien cuadrado y demás, como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen, la parte de la izquierda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando intento probar el funcionamiento de la app desde la máquina virtual de Android Studio todo me aparece movido de sitio, concretamente arriba a la izquierda (es la imagen de arriba a la derecha).

¿Alguien sabe exactamente cual es el problema? Soy muy nuevo con Android Studio así que imagino que debe de ser cualquier nimiedad. Dejo a continuación el código xml por si sirve de ayuda:

Una parte del código no aparece no sé porque, lo pongo como imagen (es el código inicial, antes de TextView). Abajo del todo el código no aparece pero se cierra correctamente el constraintlayout:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/NomCognoms"
    android:layout_width="112dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:text="Nom i cognoms"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.058"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.033" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_nomcognoms"
    android:layout_width="179dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="47dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/botoAcceptar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="236dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/botoCancelar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="299dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
```

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Estas usando ConstraintLayout, si deseas usarlo revisa : https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html  o cambia el layout a RelativeLayout o LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está que en que usas `tools:...` eso es para vista de diseño, por eso te muestra todo "bien" pero los controles no los tienes encadenados y por eso salen todo juntos.

si te fijas el primer elemento si que estableces encadenamiento:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.058"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

pero los otros nada...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para solventar elimina todos los `tools:` y ve a la pantalla azul donde puedes ver los pivotes `arriba, derecha, abajo, izquierda` y haz los encadenamientos para ajustarlos a la posición adecuada.

Comment: No tenía ni idea del funcionamiento de la pantalla azul. La he estado toqueteando y he conseguido que todo quede a la perfección. Muchas gracias!